# Server version error while i am trying to connect to Heidisql

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, visual-studio, heidisql

I must connect one database present in `HeidiSql` to my .Net project in visual studio. When i debug my project while i am doing connection with db i obtain the error in the field `Server Version` with the description '.server Version has generated an exception of type `System.InvalidOperationException` '. Do you know what is the reason?

My connection string is :

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TicketDB"
     connectionString="server=localhost;user id=root;password=Omega;database=crm6"
     providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The code is:

```
public void getNumberAllTicketOpen()
    {

        try
        {
            clDataBase ticketDB = new clDataBase();

            string sQuery = "SELECT * from ticket";
            DataTable ticket = ticketDB.ExecuteDataTable(sQuery, null, false);
            Console.WriteLine("i am here!");

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Errore : " + e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {

        }

    }

public DataTable ExecuteDataTable(string CommandText, List<SqlParameter> Params = null, bool isStoredProcedure = true)
        {
            SqlConnection oCnn = null;
            SqlCommand oCmd = null;
            SqlDataAdapter oAdap = null;
            try
            {
                **oCnn = new SqlConnection(this.connectionString);
                oCnn.Open();**  //this is the line that launch the error

                oCmd = new SqlCommand(CommandText, oCnn);
                if (isStoredProcedure)
                    oCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                else
                    oCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

                oCmd.CommandTimeout = this.commandTimeOut;

                if (Params != null)
                {
                    foreach (SqlParameter p in Params)
                        oCmd.Parameters.Add(p);
                }

                oAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(oCmd);
                DataTable ResultTable = new DataTable();
                oAdap.Fill(ResultTable);


                return ResultTable;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error("Errore esecuzione " + CommandText, ex, MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name + " in " + MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Module.Assembly.FullName);
                throw;
            }
}
```

[oCnn = new SqlConnection(this.connectionString);
                    oCnn.Open(); //this is the line with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNco2.png)
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Show the code that throws this exception plus the ten lines before and after it

Comment: Caius Jard thank you for your response...i have added the code

Comment: Where in that code do you retrieve ServerVersion? Please show a screenshot of this error, exactly what you see on your screen when you see it?

Comment: Caius Jard i have added the screenshot that show the error at the link below the code

Answer (score 0):

The error you are showing is an error encountered by the Visual Studio debugger attempting to view a property of a `SqlConnection` object.

The property in question is `ServerVersion`.  I'm guessing the connection would only know what version of MySQL is running on the server when it actually manages to connect to the server, but at the point you've stopped the code, it hasn't connected yet.  It doesn't make sense to return the server version at that point, so throwing an `InvalidOperationException` is an appropriate response.

I see exceptions like this in the VS debugger quite often.  They are nothing to worry about.  Not every property on every object is valid all the time.

Comment: Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my problem.
I was trying to connect to a mySQL database but there were error in my code. I have resolved with the installation of the package MySql.Data with NuGet and the replacement in the code of SqlConnection, SqlCommand, SqlDataAdapter respectively with MysqlConnection, MySqlCommand, MySqlDataAdapter. Below i write the modified code:

```
  public DataTable ExecuteDataTable(string CommandText, List<MySqlParameter> Params = null, bool isStoredProcedure = true)
        {
            MySqlConnection oCnn = null;
            MySqlCommand oCmd = null;
            MySqlDataAdapter oAdap = null;
            try
            {
                oCnn = new MySqlConnection(this.connectionString);
                oCnn.Open();

                oCmd = new MySqlCommand(CommandText, oCnn);
                if (isStoredProcedure)
                    oCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                else
                    oCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

                oCmd.CommandTimeout = this.commandTimeOut;

                if (Params != null)
                {
                    foreach (MySqlParameter p in Params)
                        oCmd.Parameters.Add(p);
                }

                oAdap = new MySqlDataAdapter(oCmd);
                DataTable ResultTable = new DataTable();
                oAdap.Fill(ResultTable);


                return ResultTable;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error("Errore esecuzione " + CommandText, ex, MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name + " in " + MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Module.Assembly.FullName);
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (oCnn != null)
                {
                    if (oCnn.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                        oCnn.Close();
                    oCnn.Dispose();
                }

                if (oAdap != null)
                    oAdap.Dispose();

                if (oCmd != null)
                    oCmd.Dispose();

                if (Params != null)
                {
                    Params.Clear();
                    Params = null;
                }
            }
```